# adding variables numical values (newb question)

Tags: vb.net, math, variables

Yesterday i had a look at how to set values of variables from nummbers stored in external txt files

the variables then needed to be added up so i used trial and  error first

((XVAL) + (NEWVAL))

assuming that XVAL was set to 10 and NEWVAL was set to 20 i expected to get the answer of thirty but waqs presented with the new value of 10 20

VB.net pysicaly added the two values together but i wanted the mathematical product of the two which is ((10) + (20)) = 30

yep its a newb question could anyone explain how to achieve what im affter

Answer (score 4):

`XVAL` and `NEWVAL` are strings, so they are simply being concatenated together. You need to convert them to integers, so that VB.NET will treat them as such. To do this, use the [`Int32.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) method.

```
Dim intXVAL As Integer = Int32.Parse(XVAL)
Dim intNEWVAL as Integer = Int32.Parse(NEWVAL)

Dim result = intXVAL + intNEWVAL
```

Comment: +1 for using standard .NET BCL functions rather than VB-specific functions that are only present for backward compatibility.

Comment: @Adam: I really don't know what's with the VB-specific hate, but I'll ask you the same question you asked me: Do you have any support for the assertion that functions like `CInt` exist exclusively for backward compatibility? They're written just like any other function in the framework, and simply add some extra features that be handy for a newbie to your so-called "standard" `Parse` methods.

Comment: @Cody: They aren't written like every other function in the framework; VB-specific functions are "classless" (they are the only "global functions" available). They are not part of the BCL, and thus do not have precise analogs in other .NET languages. There's no reason for non-legacy code to use functions that are specific to one language when things like `Convert.ToInt32` exist. I fail to see how `CInt` (apart from being only four characters) could be simpler to understand than `Convert.ToInt32` or `Integer.Parse`.

Comment: @Adam: You're correct that they're not part of the BCL, but wrong in saying that they're "global functions." I was admittedly a little sloppy in my last comment in saying they're written like any other function in the framework—I meant that they're not some type of "legacy" code that you're incurring a penalty for calling (distinct from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility` namespace). They are actually *operators* and they compile directly to IL just like any other code that you might write; why does it matter if there are precise analogs available? The reason they might be easier to...

Comment: understand is because they provide some [additional functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx), like applying specific rounding rules to fractions, respecting culture, short-circuiting unnecessary conversions, determining the best conversion route at compile-time, etc. Also see this [blog post](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2004/05/31/1100.aspx), which explains these issues in much greater detail.

Comment: @Cody: I'm not saying that there's a performance penalty associated with using the VB-specific functions, but what I'm reading you as saying is that the fact that they're operators (which is not exactly true...a fact actually pointed out in the comments to the blog post you linked to) somehow makes *them* faster. This is equally untrue. While it's true that certain circumstances can yield *theoretically* (and purely theoretically) faster code, since, for example, `CInt(doubleValue)` will use the `conv.i4` opcode (instead of calling the `Convert.ToInt32(Double value)` overload, which does

Comment: the same thing). While you're obviously correct in saying that these operators aren't functions, their syntax *looks* like they are, and that's what any new user who uses them is going to think they are. Thus you're advocating that someone who is new to the language (and probably OOP as well) use something that at least *by all appearances* is something that violates the idea that classes--not functions--are the first-class citizens of the OOP .NET languages like VB.NET and C# so that they gain...what, again?

Answer (score 1):

You want to cast them to a number first.
Try **CDbl**.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa263426 for more.

edit: Oops, thought you were talking about VBA.
Try using Double.Parse(YOURVALUE) if you're talking about VB.NET.

Comment: Unless you need a floating point number's larger value range (at the sacrifice of precision), don't use them.

Comment: He didn't say anything about precision, so I just wanted to be sure :)

Comment: @J. Vermeire: True enough, but his example values are integers, and if you start a newbie down the road with doubles when integers will do, he may just use them for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Val() function?

```
Val(XVAL) + Val(NEWVAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading from a text file I assume that you are reading your values out as strings, so when you do this:

```
((XVAL) + (NEWVAL))
```

It is effectively concatenating the two strings together.  In order to get the mathematical product of the two values these need to be int/integers which is the number type.

There are a number of ways you can do this, but in essence you have to 'cast' the strings to ints and then do your calculation.

So in vb.net it would be something like this (pseudo code):

```
Dim xval As String = "10"
Dim newval As String = "20"

Dim x As Integer = Int32.Parse(xval)
Dim n As Integer = Int32.Parse(newval)

Dim prod As Integer = x + n

Console.WriteLine(prod)
```

There are a number of other methods of doing this, for example using:

```
int.Parse(...)
```

or

```
Integer.TryParse(...)
```

More information on these sorts of type conversions can be found here:

http://dotnetperls.com/integer-parse-vbnet

One thing to bear in mind with these sorts of conversions is that you have to be certain that your input data is convertable.  Otherwise your code will throw exceptions.  This is where TryParse is useful as you can use this to check the inputs and handle invalid inputs without the need for exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The **`+`** operator in VB.NET (for backwards-compatibility reasons) means *both* add and concatenate depending on the types of the variables it is being used with. With two numeric types (`Integer`, `Single`, `Double`, etc.), it adds the values together as you would expect. However, with `String` types, it concatenates the two strings.

Presumably, then, your `XVAL` and `NEWVAL` variables are `String` types because they're being read out of a text file, which is causing VB.NET to concatenate them into a new string instead of add them together. To get the behavior you're expecting, you need to convert them to numeric types.

Some of the other answers suggest casting simply casting the string values to numeric types (`CInt`, `CSng`, `CDbl`, etc.), but this may not work as expected if the value contained by your string cannot be converted to number. The `Int32.Parse` method will throw an exception if the value held by your string cannot be represented as a number. This is especially important to keep in mind if you're reading values from a text file that are not guaranteed to adhere to any particular constraints.

Instead, you probably want to use something like **[`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)**, which returns a `Boolean` value indicating whether or not the conversion succeeded and will not throw an exception.

Comment: Any support for the assertion that `+` is used for concatenation for only backward-compatibility reasons? `+` also concatenates strings in C# and Java, and is fairly standard in modern languages.

Comment: @Adam: You're right about other languages, but it's not necessarily standard in VB, given its traditionally loose typing and the tendency of lots of developers to work with things like `Option Strict` off. The ampersand was introduced *specifically* for string concatenation in an early version of pre-.NET Visual Basic and was almost universally recommended as a best practice. In fact, it still is, according to every version of [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Interesting; I wasn't aware of that. Given the shenanigans that VB.NET will go through to figure out what you mean, it probably is wiser to use the ampersand.